# I can't get a voice channel from user [Discord.js v12]

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I can't get a voice channel from user with Discord.js v12.

This is what I tried:

```js
let voicech = message.member.VoiceChannel;
console.log(voicech);
if (!voicech) {
    channel = message.channel;
    channel.send("หาช่องไม่เจอกรุณาเข้าช่องเสียง")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to discord.js [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember). `GuildMember` does not have a `.VoiceChannel` property which you are trying to access.

What `GuildMember` has is a `VoiceState`, access that (using `.voice` property) and get the `VoiceChannel` (using `.channel` property) like this:

```js
const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
```